# Vue props undefined when passing from parent component to child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Having an issue passing two data members from my parent's data method to the child component's props. Basically, I'm setting the data values inside my parent component, binding them to my child component invocation inside the HTML template. Then I'm attempting to reference this passed data inside the child'd 'props'.

But I keep getting this inside my Vue dev tools:

```
 props
   date: undefined
   title: undefined
```

Here's my code:

**App.vue** (showing for reference only. i don't expect my issue is with this code)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <Header />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Header from '@/components/Header.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Header
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Home.vue** (Parent component)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header :title="title" :date="date" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: "SOME NEWS",
      date: moment().format("dddd, MMMM D, YYYY") 
    }
  },
  components: {
    Header
  }
};
</script>
```

**Header.vue** (Child component)

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ getTitle() }}</h1>
    <h3>{{ getDate() }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    method: {
      getTitle() {
        return this.title
      },
      getDate() {
        return this.date
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: If I had a working example, I would not have posted this question.

Comment: *But I keep getting this inside my Vue dev tools:* This happens without a working example?

Comment: The code I provided is what I have, and it's not working and the Vue dev tools (for Chrome) shows that the two properties, title and date, are undefined.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of a working example? It is the code which shows your error, working in an environment, like a code snippet/code sandbox.

Comment: Dude, the code I included is what produces that error. I have nothing else to show.

Comment: Ok I'm going to explain again. You posted code here, and an error. A really genius, god-gifted extremely skilled programmer will take one look at both, and spew the reason for your error in a nanosecond. Most of us sadly, aren't, so we mortals would have to copy this code to an online playground, or our own machines, run it, see the console, debug the code and come up with a solution (or not)

Comment: This is where you come into the picture, where you create an example with all the code in the question, where people can directly run it, and debug. Since you are the one facing the issue, it is your job to make sure others are able to run it and find the same error as you do. You can use codesandbox, codepen, jsfiddle, stackblitz..there are many

Comment: Its good that this time your error didn't need much debugging, but it might some other time, so be sure to create working examples then.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Thanks for weighing in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct in your App component code you should use `<Home />` component, but you use `<Header />` instead. Example:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <Home />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Home from '@/components/Home.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Home
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The Home component is inside the 'views' directory, and does not need to be registered inside App.vue. My Header component, however, needs to be displayed on every page, so included it inside App.vue and registered as a component.

Comment: Ok, but you included your Header component inside Home. And you passed props from Home to Header, but your Home component not used anywhere. It will never showed.

Comment: I see what you mean now. So App.vue should be my Parent, not Home.vue. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Please try to replace Header with Home in you App component, and you will see how it works.